# How to implement an ILogger to send messages to a SignalR Hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, ilogger

I want to build a LogView which shows the latest log messages. So I've built a really simple setup but I fail at Dependency Injection.

Here's my attempt at an implementation. I've skipped the non-crucial parts.

```
public class SignalRLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly IHubContext<LogHub> _hub;

    public SignalRLogger(IHubContext<LogHub> hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        var msg = $"[{logLevel}] {formatter(state, exception)}";

        _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", msg);
    }
}

public class SignalrRLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private SignalRLogger _logger;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _logger = null;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        if (_logger == null)
        {
            _logger = new SignalRLogger(????);
        }

        return _logger;
    }
}
```

My problem basically is that I can't inject an `IHubContext` and I'm not sure how to solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `LoggerProvider` is created before `SignalR` hubs are registered. So when the logger provider is created the `IServiceProvider` has not been initialized to know about any `IHubContext<T>` objects.

The only way I can find to solve it is to provide the `IServiceProvider` to your `ILogger` and let it get an instance of the `IHubContext` when it needs it.

Your logger class needs to accept an `IServiceProvider` in it's constructor and then use that object to retrieve the `IHubContext` on demand:

```
public class SignalRLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _sp;

    public SignalRLogger(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _sp = sp;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        var hub = _sp.GetService<IHubContext<LogHub>>();

        if (hub != null)
        {
            var msg = $"[{logLevel}] {formatter(state, exception)}";

            hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

We need to check that the `IHubContext` has been retrieved from the service provider as the logger can be called before the hub has been registered. And this is one of the downsides to using SignalR as a logger because you will miss some early messages before the `HubContext` can be accessed (but this may be acceptable to you).

NOTE: You can improve this to store the hub instead of getting it on every log call - but I'll leave that for you to implement :-)

Now you need to change your provider to supply that parameter when it creates the logger:

```
public class SignalrRLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private SignalRLogger _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _sp;

    public SignalrRLoggerProvider(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _sp = sp;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        if (_logger == null)
        {
            _logger = new SignalRLogger(_sp);
        }

        return _logger;
    }
}
```

Finally you need to provider the `IServiceProvider` to the logger provider:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
        {
            var sp = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            builder.AddProvider(new SignalrRLoggerProvider(sp));
        });
```

We need to call the `BuildServiceProvider` method to create the interface we need as it's not available in `ConfigureLogging` call - but it will give us the correct interface to use.

Comment: Okay this works fine-ish. The creating-process and everything works. But when it comes to sending messages they wont be received on the client side. I think the issue is that hubs are transient - is that possible?
Anyway the issue isn't really related to the question. Should I accept the answer? I mean it (kinda) solved my issue

Comment: When I Inject a IHubContext<LogHub> into a background task, the client is receiving messages. It appears it wont be received when the ctx is created by the ServiceProvider